# VB.net - Splitting lines from text file using multiple characters

Tags: vb.net, text, split

I want to make it so that my program will search a text file, and upon finding the keyword will declare all text as a string until it "sees" the next keyword.  As if you were highlighting text with your mouse.

I have this code so far,

```
    Dim objReader As New StreamReader("C:\test.txt")

    Dim file As String = ""
    Dim result As String

    If Not file Is Nothing Then
        file = objReader.ReadLine()
        result = file.Split("keyword")(1).Split("keyword2")(0)
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result)
    End If
```

now this works fine if I am trying to work with single characters or letters etc, but words will result in copying something seemingly random in the text file.

Thanks for all your help in advance and apologies for my "noobiness".

Comment: You want to search through the text until you find the index of the occurrence of a specific word. Then, from there, you'd like to add all text after that index, up until another specific word is found, into a string? Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Okay, good. I'm going to throw some code together real quick. Check back here soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function should do the trick.

```
Function GetSubString(ByVal inText As String, ByVal firstWord As String, ByVal secondWord As String) As String
    Dim indexFirst As Integer = inText.IndexOf(firstWord)
    Dim indexSecond As Integer = inText.IndexOf(secondWord)
    Return inText.Substring(indexFirst, indexSecond - indexFirst + secondWord.Length)
End Function
```

Use It like this:

```
GetSubString(RichTextBox1.Text, "quick", "over")
```

Using this text:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

This is returned:

> quick brown fox jumps over

Comment: Seems great!  but how would I make this search a text file?

Comment: `My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Test.txt")` will read all the text from a given file. Just pass that over to the function along with the desired two words.

Comment: If the you consider my answer correct, please flag it as accepted. You'll find that more users will be willing to take the time to answer your future questions if they can see that you take the time to accept answers when appropriate. Thanks

Comment: Just one thing, sorry for inconvenience, but it returns an error upon using it for me, "StartIndex cannot be less than zero."  on the return line, I'm probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Post your text and the words you're searching for and I'll take a look

Comment: That error is thrown when the first word cannot be found. Make sure that the word is in the input text first. You can check like this: `inText.contains("Word")`

Comment: Am I supposed to be placing the two words anywhere other than `GetSubString(RichTextBox1.Text, "quick", "over")` ? I don't have much experience with functions.  Might just be your worst "in-need" ever.

Comment: Nope. Your first word is where "quick" is and your second is where "over" is. "RichTextBox1.Text" is the text that you're searching. Before you call the function, make sure your first and second words are in the text to begin with. If not, you'll get an error.

Comment: Where does the text get produced then?

Comment: `Dim FoundText as string = GetSubString("input text will go here", "text", "go")` Does that help any?

Comment: Made all the difference, I'm terribly sorry, if there's any way I can make it up to you..

Comment: Don't be sorry. I'm just glad I could help! :)

Comment: I believe it works fine, but for me it returns OutOfRange exception - probably due to very large file I'm using.